# How to restrict base tag to certain hyperlinks

Tags: html, iframe, radix

I am using a `base` tag with an `iframe` tag and I would like to know how I can restrict certain links that open in the `iframe`.

e.g I have a menu panel and when clicked on menu link that desired page is displayed in the iframe.

```
<div class="start">
    <h1 class="start">Geek Box <img src="box_icon.png" alt="Box width=" 40" height="40"></h1>
    <hr />
</div>
<div class="table">
    <table class="table" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="Chart.html">Tech Charts</a></td>
            <td><a href="Video.html">Videos</a></td>
            <td><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<hr />
<br />

<div>
    <table border="1" width=100% height="500px" style="text-align:center">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%"><a href="phone.html">Smart Phones</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="laptop.html">Laptops</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="Desktop.html">Dektops</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="Tablets.html">Tablets</a></td>
        </tr>
        <base target='display' />
        <tr><td colspan="4"><iframe name="display" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="500px" /> </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do... do you want to prevent links appearing in the iframe you opened or prevent links opening your iframe...? what do you mean by "base tag" exactly here...?

Comment: im trying to prevent links appearing in the iframe.

Comment: and what is a "base tag"?

Comment: <base> tag displays a hyperlink on the current page with in a iframe, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: do you mean you want some of the links appear in the iframe, and others separately (either loading in the same window or another one), and not in the iframe?

Comment: hope my answer will help...

Comment: it is custom at this site to reward answerers if you find they're being helpful, so please upvote and/or accept my answer as the correct one if you feel it helped / answered your question, otherwise you may want to let me know which part was not addressed in your question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like some of the pages to open in the `iframe`, and others in either the same window or another one (or whatever other way), ie. *not* in the `iftame`.

This won't work with the `base` tag using your example because...

> The HTML `<base>` element specifies the base URL to use for **all** relative URLs contained within a document.

...and also

> There can be only one `<base>` element in a document.

...so using another `base` tag would not make it work the way you want it.

Instead you'll have to get rid of the `base` tag, and add the `target` attribute to each of those links that you want to appear in the `iframe`.

So assuming you would like to open only the "sub-menus" (so they seem at least, ie. phone, laptop... etc) in the `iframe`, this is what I suggest you change your code to:

```
<div>
    <table border="1" width=100% height="500px" style="text-align:center">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%"><a href="phone.html" target='display'>Smart Phones</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="laptop.html" target='display'>Laptops</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="Desktop.html" target='display'>Dektops</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="Tablets.html" target='display'>Tablets</a></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Notice I have removed the 'base' tag! -->
        <tr><td colspan="4"><iframe name="display" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="500px" /> </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

...and you can leave the rest of your code intact.

Quoted source: [`<base` - HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: Thank you this helps soo much

Comment: don't hesitate to accept this as the correct answer (gray check mark next to the voting buttons), or even vote up, if you feel like it ;)